# Rails validate with polish string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding

Question for polish users. I have validation for first name like this:

```
:format => {:with => /\A[a-zA-Z]+\z/}
```

how can i add polish to this - ążźćńęółśż

Comment: what about /[[:lower:][:upper:]]+/u

Comment: { :with => /\A[a-zA-Z]+\z//[[:lower:][:upper:]]+/u }   ?

Comment: { :with => /[[:lower:][:upper:]]+/u }

Comment: doesnt work, syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting tASSOC

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate that the first name contains non accented letters and letters from that particular subset, I think that the most accurate way of doing it is by explicitly declaring the subset in the Regex. Something like this:

```
:format => { :with => /\A[ążźćńęółśża-zA-Z]\z/ }
```